# SOAP Web Services in Flash Builder 4.5 - won't accept a string with spaces or quotes

Tags: actionscript-3, web-services, soap, flex4, flash-builder

When using SOAP web services in Flash Builder, I am able to use the web services tool and test making service calls without any issue.  I can pass strings that contain spaces, double and single quotes with great success.  However, when I write code to send a string containing spaces or quotes, the web service doesn't return a success response.  If I remove the quotes and/or spaces, success.  I've tried wrapping the string in  tags, but I don't know what else to do.  I'm at a loss and need help.  Anybody?

Comment: I have also tried escaping the value of the string, first.  Still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the version of SOAP services being returned.  Currently, Flex can only handle SOAP 1.1.  The services that we had built initially were SOAP 1.2.  This is a known issue with Adobe, but they've done nothing about it as of yet.

We rebuilt the web services in SOAP 1.1 from an earlier version of the .NET framework and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you in control of the web services on the server? If so, base64 encode the data when you send it, and unencode it in the web service. Do the reverse when the web service returns data to flex.

If you don't have control, you can escape the parameters(using escape()).

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  This was an issue on the backend.  It turned out that the web services I needed returned were SOAP1 and the version that was being returned was higher and the schema was not compatible.  My issue has been resolved.  Thank you for the input!